# Where to find animation for character 阝?

Tags: characters

I seel only https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_170 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_163 with (traditional?) version animated. [Many sites don't know this characted](http://www.strokeorder.info/mandarin.php?q=%E9%98%9D) at all. And others don't give animated gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This animation is on [wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E9%98%9D-order.gif):

[image]

- There is also another one here on [kanshudo](https://www.kanshudo.com/kanji/%E9%98%9D) but it's not a gif.

Answer (score 0):

阝and⻏ and ⻖are seldom written in single form in daily life.

It is more easy to find some animation from common characters like [邢](http://www.strokeorder.info/mandarin.php?q=%E9%82%A2) and [阡](http://www.strokeorder.info/mandarin.php?q=%E9%98%A1).

If you insist to have their animations, just down those gif files and modify them to your satisfaction.